# mvn test -P using <argLine> doesn't work with a value containing @ character

Tags: maven, unit-testing, maven-profiles

I am trying to set a maven profile for my unit-tests and two of all the values are containing an @ character.

-DKEY=value:@value -DKEY2=value2:n:@value2

Now everything in between the first @ and second @ is red and the mvn test -P command does not run.
I have tried making the -D:s strings with "" and '' and also tried putting the values into  and fetching them in my  with ${name in properties} without success.
Same error message but no red line is the only difference.

Help?

Comment: Use quotes around each -D to protect the values.  How to do that depends on your operating system and command interpreter

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that has been tried and did not fix my problem.
The problem is still there - I have been working on other parts of the application so to find a solution is still relevant!